# Ruby NET::FTP, Dolby FTP issue with mkdir

Tags: ruby, ftp

Normally, an FTP server using the MKD cmd expects a status code: 257. (Cf: RFC 959)

I have a Dolby FTP server returns a status code: 250 when the mkdir cmd is successful. (msg returns: PATH FOLDER created successfully)

I have an issue with that, because Ruby NET::FTP expects only status code 257 and so raise an error.

Has anyone had the same problem with a FTP server and can help me resolve the issue?